# Define commands programmatically

Tags: vimscript

I'd like to add commands in my `.vimrc` programmatically in a function. For example, instead of hardcoding commands like this

```
command! MyCommand echom "My command"
```

I'd prefer to add them in a simple function like this

```
function! AddCommands()

  for commandName in ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    " TODO: Add a command with the given name that prints something
  endfor

endfunction
```

How can I add the commands `One`, `Two`, and `Three` using the for loop above?

---

Once I got that working, I want to read a file containing file paths and automatically create commands that open those files. I call that file "bookmarks file".

A line in the bookmarks file looks like this:

> BookmarkName: /path/to/bookmarked/file.txt

Here's what I got so far:

```
" Read file paths from our bookmark file 
" and create a command for each bookmark that, when executed, opens the
" file in a new tab.
function! ReadBookmarks()
  let bookmarks = readfile(fnameescape($BOOKMARKS_FILE))
  let bookmarkSeparator = ": "
  for bookmark in bookmarks
    let nameAndPath = split(bookmark, bookmarkSeparator)
    let name = nameAndPath[0]
    let path = nameAndPath[1]

    " TODO: Add a command that opens the file in a new tab
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: This isn't even phrased as a question, and it is in no way clear that your own answer is the one you were looking for.

Comment: Well, the TODO in the code makes clear what I was looking for, i.e., code that adds commands to Vim.

Comment: Yes. But this is a question/answer site. The question should not be implicit, it should be explicit. If you rephrase and improve the question, then I would vote to reopen.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll update my question to make what I was asking for more explicit.

Comment: I voted to reopen because, after your edit, it seems pretty clear to me what you're asking. However, I think the title is still pretty misleading: a). I thought the question was going to be about how to persist changes made *at runtime* in your .vimrc b). What you're actually asking about (how to build ex-commands from variables using `execute`) is in no way specific to code that exists in the .vimrc. I also agree with @statox that a marginally less-contrived example would improve the question.

Comment: I edited the title to what I think you're asking, but I will leave the re-opening to other users, since I'd like a less-contrived example too.

Comment: I added a more involved example; the code for which I am actually using the programmatic definition of commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## With [`execute`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html)

This does the trick:

```
function! AddCommands()

  for commandName in ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    " Adds a command that, when executed, prints its own name
    execute "command! " . commandName . " echom \"" . commandName . "\""
  endfor

endfunction
```

Now I can call, for example, `:Three` which will print

> Three

---

The missing lines in the example involving the bookmarks file are thus:

```
let openFileCommand = "command! " . name . " :tabe " . path
execute openFileCommand
```

The whole example:

```
function! ReadBookmarks()
  let bookmarks = readfile(fnameescape($BOOKMARKS_FILE))
  let bookmarkSeparator = ": "
  for bookmark in bookmarks
    let nameAndPath = split(bookmark, bookmarkSeparator)
    let name = nameAndPath[0]
    let path = nameAndPath[1]

    " This adds a command that opens the file in a new tab
    let openFileCommand = "command! " . name . " :tabe " . path
    execute openFileCommand
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: I can't see a use case where this would be useful. You are still hardcoding the name of your command but in two separate place. And maybe this way to do it reduce your code when you have a lot of commands like this but once again it can't see a case where you'd need a lot of commands of this type. Could you give us a real world example?

Comment: Sure, I added the code for which I actually used the programmatic definition of commands.

Comment: Thanks for your example, that's an interesting way to handle your bookmarks :)

Comment: I am always happy to share! What's your way of handling bookmarks? Netrw, Nerdtree?

Comment: I don't use bookmarks, I use a combination of `find` and [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) To find my files and search my MRU and I have the mark `'V` set on my vimrc. I don't use Netrw anymore because it was too buggy and [NerdTree is bad](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) ;)